# Python imports with __init__.py not working for unknown reasons

Tags: python, import

I'm having issues with importing things from other files in python. I have a setup that looks something like this:

```
program/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    common/
        __init__.py
        file3.py
```

Where in files 1 and 2 I say `import common`. For some reason however, the import fails, saying `no module named common`. The weirder thing about this is that creating a new file with a different name with it's own `__init__.py`, it imports perfectly fine.

The full backstory is that I was working on these files on another computer, then emailed them to myself and loaded them back onto my actual computer. This is when the import error occurred. What I did to reload the files is I simply deleted the old ones (including the file structure) and rebuilt it with the files I emailed to myself. Could this have any effect on imports?

EDIT: I just realized that when I downloaded the files I actually had two `__init__.py`'s, one with an ordinary name, and another one with the number `1` at the end (to distinguish the difference). I renamed the file so it's just `__init__.py`, but I can't import from it at all. Even if I move that file to a new folder it gives me an import error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is the entry point of your program, i.e. how are you invoking python (e.g. `python program/file.py`)?

Comment: `'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\python programs\\program\\file1.py'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
from common import file3, file4
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it turns out all I had to do was change the name of the original `__init__.py`, make a new `__init__.py` from scratch, copy over all the code, and then delete the original `__init__.py`. Not sure what exactly was causing it to fail like it did, but at least I have a solution now.